# Maven including ocijdbc19 in java.library.path

Tags: java, oracle, maven

**TL;DR:**

This is the error I'm getting:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc19 in java.library.path
```

How do I include a zipped DLL file in a maven project? And how do I specify which DLL lib to use based on the running operating system (Windows/Linux)?

---

I'm trying to use ocijdbc19 in my maven project. It can be downloaded from here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html

Specifically version 19.3.0.0:
https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/nt/instantclient/19300/instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip

And it is used with this driver (Running in **Java 11**):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
  <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

There is no ojdbc10 version 19.6.0.0 so I had to downgrade ocijdbc19 to match.

It packaged as a zip file with a DLL file in it. How do I include it in my project in such a way that it will work while packaged?

Here is the error:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc19 in java.library.path
```

The `java.library.path` includes the working directory `./` but that is where the pom is located.

I've tried adding the JVM Option `-Djava.library.path=".\lib"`, but then that overrides the initial value completely and I get this error:

```
lib\ocijdbc19.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Another issue is I'm developing on a Windows machine, but this project will be deployed on a linux machine. There are separate versions of ocijdbc19 for the different OSes. The Maven configuration needs to switch between each package.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use OCI? Why not use the thin (pure java) driver instead?

Comment: I need it for Debezium library: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/oracle.html#deploying-a-connector

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Java 11. It's in the past.